# hidden part video, from youtube

Tags: css, safari, youtube

I have video from youtube, i want hidden some place from this video, this is my code

```
 <div style="width: 200px; height: 315px; overflow: hidden">
        <iframe width="560" height="315"    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/AMoLwrarElA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

this works good in all browsers, except safari, in safari is visible all video, someone know why?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a semi-colon at the end of hidden:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Also try adding:

```
clear:both;
```

To your div style.

Comment: This not helps, please tell, in your browser, video is hidden after apply:  
 clear:both;

?

Comment: Yes, this works for me in all browsers. Is your Safari up to date?

Comment: Yes my safari is new version, I test this code in two computers and is not working no one computer exactly in safari

Answer (score 1):

[image: Image shows absolute positioned div covering an iframe]

As the image shows, the way to do this is:

```
body
  div (position = absolute, top = iframe.top, right = iframe.right, width = 350px)
  iframe (position = absolute or relative, width = 750px)
```

**here absolute positioned div is the red striped area**

You can use jquery to get iframes left top right bottom:

```
<body>
 <div class="cover"></div>
 <iframe/>
 <script>
   $(function(){
     var top = iframe.top
     var right = iframe.right
     $("cover")[0].top = top;
     $("cover")[0].right = right;
     //..
   });
 </script>
</body>
```

Sorry I have less time, cannot explain more, if this does not work I will try again

Comment: **DO NOT JUST UPVOTE, MARK IT AS THE ANSWER**

Answer (score 0):

this code decided this problem

```
<div style="width: 200px; height: 315px; overflow: hidden;">
<object width="560" height="315" style="float:left; overflow: hidden;">
    <param name="movie"    value="http://www.youtube.com/v/AMoLwrarElA&hl=ru_RU&fs=1&rel=0&border=0"/>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/>
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque"/>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/AMoLwrarElA&hl=ru_RU&fs=1&rel=0&border=0" wmode="opaque" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="560" height="315"/>
</object>
</div>
```